# Posting a number value to an endpoint in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, post

```
final response = await http.post(
Uri.parse(url),
body: {"id": 0, "name": "bhag"},
    );
```

Why do I get the following error when I execute the above code in **flutter web**? and is there any other ways to pass number in the post body?

**ERROR:**

> ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate
> expression 'place': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not
> supported. No frame with index 15..
> Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'int'

Was trying to post an integer id to an endpoint in flutter web but the above error occurred. Using dio package to post the above body throws an 415 status code. The above code works perfectly fine if the id had an string value.

Comment: With `POST`, when using x-form-urlencoded (as you are) you can only string->string pairs. If you want to send an int, you need to convert it first to a string. You could use `'id': '0',` or `'id': 0.toString(),`

Comment: what should i do to include exact numbers and list of objects in the post body?